# How to reach Munich Hbf from Munich's Airport (Terminal 2)? Disabled person

Tags: munich, lufthansa, accessibility, lot-polish-airlines

Recently I asked here a question [about reaching Marktoberdorf from Munich's Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73349/how-can-i-reach-marktoberdorf-from-munich-airport-disabled-person/73372#73372). @user24582 gave me very helpful information and links.

I contacted Mobility service of the Deutsche Bahn and asked if they will be able to help me with my journey. They advised me the connection:

[image: the connection]

Also, they said that *In Munich Hbf and in Augsburg Hbf we can organize a help for you.* So it's very, very helpful.

I think I will accept this option, however, I still have a question (of course, I will ask Mobility service of the Deutsche Bahn too):

When I get out of the plane (I land at Terminal 2 at Munich's airport), where should I go to reach München Flughafen Terminal? I mean, literally, just follow the signs and ... ask people? I must admit, I'm a bit confused (although I've flied before, to London, Stavanger, ...).

I've already contacted LOT airlines and they said they are not able to help with guiding me to Hbf.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**EDIT:**
**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Thanks to your help (thank you, @neo) I have contacted Munich's airport (sent an e-mail to `mobility@munich-airport.de`), gave them my flight details, and they promised to help me from Terminal 2 to the train station.

Also, Deutsche Bahn mobility service is very helpful. I asked them so many questions and they politely and patiently explained everything to me. However, I am ashamed of asking them so many questions, so I decided to ask (I hope) my last question here.

With the help of Deutsche Bahn mobility service, I will be able to book the ticket to Marktoberdorf, here are connection details:

[image: connection details]

1. If I understand it right, I only need to buy the ticket to get from
   Terminal 2 to München Flughafen Terminal, right?
2. The question is, if it is possible to book such ticket also online? 
   It seems there's no train from Terminal 2 to München Flughafen Terminal, since using Deutsche Bahn's [website](https://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/index.shtml), I can't find such connection.

Is it only the bus which is available?

Can I book the bus online?

3. I checked on Google Maps that the distance from Terminal 2 to
   München Flughafen Terminal is about 33 km (takes 41 minutes by
   bus). My plane lands at 9:00 am in Munich, and at 10:33 I have a
   train from München Flughafen Terminal. Is it possible to make it on
   time, from Terminal 2 to München Flughafen Terminal?
4. If eventually, I would not be able to buy the ticket from Terminal 2 to München Flughafen Terminal, is it possible to buy it on site? Can I pay in cash there?

Comment: I think you mean "where do I need to go to reach the train station "München Flughafen Terminal" from the arrival gate at the airport?", no? The connection you show above is from the airport already, I think there might be a missunderstanding?!

Comment: @mts: Urm, you're right. I will correct it, thanks. I thought that München Flughafen Terminal IS the airport's terminal :)

Comment: Great :) Are you more worried about finding the train station in the airport or it's accessibility? Did you contact the Munich airport already?

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding with the airline: of course they can't bring you all the way to Hauptbahnhof. Ask if they can help you to get to the S-Bahn station at the airport.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that LOT offered no help as they are legally required to by EC regulation No 1107/2006. For example, they have to transmit the information to Munich Airport so that assistance can be offered upon landing.

Comment: @mts: Both! :D Nah, kidding, I think I can handle the accessibility (somehow ^^). I'm worried more about finding the right train, and if I can make it on time. Also, if you have some time, kindly please see my edit :)

Comment: @user24582: Perhaps (and I'm sure so) you're right but I have contacted Munich's airport and it seems it will all be ok, as they wrote they will be able to assist me from terminal 2 to the train station (I explained everything in my edit).

Comment: For booking Deutsche Bahn, see: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39054/fastest-way-to-get-from-frankfurt-to-karlsruhe/39098#39098

Comment: @user24582: "There might be a misunderstanding with the airline: of course they can't bring you all the way to Hauptbahnhof." - are you sure? Lufthansa cooperates with DB and sometimes offers legs of a flight connection that are actually train rides (with a Lufthansa flight attendant on board for further information!).

Comment: The train station in the airport is between the terminals and not far from where you arrive and it seems mobility will assist you. You need to book that ticket in advance (it is a saver fare and you will be bound to that IC train). The comment of @O.R.Mapper is not the case here! Please do not expand your question anymore, it is quite broad already, if you have more questions (e.g. on the train ticket) ask a new question (but for that particular issue we should already have something so do a search beforehand).

Comment: Let me just say that that train itinerary is totally borked. There are direct trains from Munich to Marktoberdorf every two hours and in the in-between hours you just need to transfer in Buchloe from one side of the platform to the other (impossible to miss).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Terminal 2 you can follow the signs to "München Airport Center". This is the building were the train to Munich Hbf departs (called "München Flughafen Terminal" by Deutsche Bahn). The building is located right next to Terminal 2 and connected by a short walk. There is no need to take a bus or buy a ticket to get there.

The train station (which is marked with the [image: white S on green background] symbol) does feature an elevator to the platform. To get there, go a bit beyond the escalator and look out for it as it is sandwiched between a restaurant and a wall and not well signed. It can be seen [here on the airport map](https://navigation.munich-airport.de/#?core.init.lon=12.56&core.init.lat=-0.28&fov=100.0&image=78001).

An alternative would be to get the [Lufthansa Airport Bus](https://www.airportbus-muenchen.de/en/home/) which departs directly from Terminal 2. However, it does not accept train tickets and I don't know how accessible it is.

In any case, Munich Airport does have a mobility service. You can either ask any member of staff or at the information desk for help getting to the train as it is quite a distance to walk. Even better would be to get in touch beforehand (at least 48 hours). In that case someone will helping you for the whole way from the airplane. They can be reached at `mobility@munich-airport.de`.

Some information on the accessibility of Munich Airport can be found in [their brochure](http://www.munich-airport.de/media/download/general/publikationen/en/barrierefrei.pdf).

Comment: I found the airport map slightly confusing. This page might help for an overview: http://www.munich-airport.de/en/consumer/anab/bahn/index.jsp - the S-Bahn is marked by a red [DB] logo on the former, a green (S) on the latter.

Comment: @user24582 Yes, unfortunately the linked map is not really clear but at least you can see the location of the elevator which I can't remember ever seeing.

Comment: Thank you, your help is precious  for me! However, could you possibly please see my edit and give some additional advices? I will be grateful.

Comment: @tlockhart See my edit. The 33km is likely a glitch in Google Maps, the two buildings are right next to each other. The airport team will bring you there, no need to worry.

Comment: I would never think that Munich Hbf  is also called "München Flughafen Terminal" :) It's worth to know! I must admit, that I'm a little less frightened than I was before asking my questions on TE. Help I got from all of you guys is invaluable. Many, many thanks!

Comment: @tlockhart Sorry, I think we have a misunderstanding. These are two different stations. The airport staff will bring you to the airport station and you board the train to Hbf which is included in the ticket and connection you posted.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I'm grateful you helped me resolve this doubt, it is good to know that this is all included in my ticket and I do not need to worry about additional tickets.

Comment: @neo As I came back from Marktoberdorf, I would like to thank you again for all the help you provided. With all the information and contacts given by you, it was super easy to reach this amazing city :) Thank you again, take care!

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your edit, I think you've got a few things mixed up.

The walking distance from Termal 2 Gate G23/G24 (for example) to the S-Bahn station "München Flughafen Terminal" is 550 meters. You don't need a bus here, and you don't need a ticket for walking :-)

https://www.google.de/maps/dir/48.3546515,11.7920726/M%C3%BCnchen+Flughafen+Terminal,+85356+M%C3%BCnchen-Flughafen/@48.3541846,11.7843918,954m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x479e137d15789d4f:0x504e185c28be3186!2m2!1d11.78597!2d48.353728!3e2

Google seems to have problems to calculate the way for pedestrians when you follow the link. In my browser it says 550 m / 8 Min.

(The is a [bus](https://www.airportbus-muenchen.de/en/times_of_departure/airport/) from terminal 2 to München Hbf, as an alternative to the S-Bahn. That might be the soucre of the confusion.)

Comment: Ok, now it is perfectly clear. I would not need to bother Deutsche Bahn with such silly questions, thanks to you ^^ I hope everything will go fine now :) Thank you!

Comment: Its been a long time since my question appeared, but I just thought that I need to thank you again. My whole trip to Germany was the greatest experience in my entire life. Bavaria is amazing, and the most beautiful place I've ever seen. Munich is the city of my dreams :) People out there are very kind and helpful - it all was just an astonishing adventure. Besides, I fell in love with Alps! You're lucky to live there! Furthermore, the mobility service teams from DB and Munich's Airport gave me unimaginable help.

Comment: And, as I wrote before, Munich was not my final destination, I was going to Marktoberdorf for the Summer School, and it turned out that their shuttle service can pick me up straight from the airport, so I did not need to go by train. However, advices and help given by DB were stunning, I'm 100% sure that I would not have a problem if I would need to go by train. Moreover, your advices helped a lot too! And I would like to truly thank you for them. I really appreciate it! Greetings from Poland, hope I will have a chance to visit Germany again in the future! Take care :)

Answer (score 2):

There's a bus from Airport to Hbf which goes something like every half hour and it was pretty accessible as far as I remember.

Just follow the signs, that's how we stumbled into in when we were in Munich.